# how to get image last launched time using awscli or boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ami

using the AWS console on the ami page I can see an attribute called Last launched time that shows the last time an instance was launched with this image (i assume) I try to get this attribute using the `describe-images` ec2 API but it doesn't show it as far as I can tell.

is there any way to get this information using code?

Answer (score 0):

ok the answer is apparently

```
aws ec2 describe-image-attribute \
--image-id ami-1234567890example \
--attribute lastLaunchedTime
```

Comment: this seems to be the intended way to get this data, but it looks like it's not returning any useful data (only the image id I already provided)

Comment: It shows the date for me. Are you sure someone launched an instance from that AMI you are querying?

Comment: yes I'm only getting {
    "ImageId": "ami-asddaasdasdasdasd"
} ok i think it's a permissions issue because from cloudshell it shows it to me

Comment: from the cloud shell it shows me the data when I use the same role but when I run it from local it doesn't, only for this attribute. I have no idea what's

Comment: @ConsciptMR could it be that you have an older version in your local installation for aws cli?